Laravel 11 Middleware Authentication with Controller's method
What should I use in controller's constructor for authenticating my methods in laravel 11.
<?php 
public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }
?>

We used write this before laravel 11.
Now what should we need to use instead of this?
I haven't tried anything

In Laravel 11, the abstract controller class no longer extends any class or uses any traits, so the old middleware() method is no longer available.
If you want to use the same functionality, your controller needs to implement the \Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\HasMiddleware interface which contains a single middleware() method.
This middleware() method returns an array of middleware to be applied inside the controller. If you want to have finer control over the methods to which the middleware will be applied or excluded then you can include an instance of the class \Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Middleware inside this array. Here's how we can rewrite your example using Laravel 11 approach:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Middleware;

class HomeController extends Controller implements \Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\HasMiddleware
{
    //
    public static function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            new Middleware(middleware: 'auth:sanctum', except: ['index', 'show']),
        ];
    }
}

Further information are available in the official documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#controller-middleware

This has changed significantly in Laravel 11.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#controller-middleware
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\HasMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Middleware;
 
class UserController extends Controller implements HasMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Get the middleware that should be assigned to the controller.
     */
    public static function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            'auth',
            new Middleware('log', only: ['index']),
            new Middleware('subscribed', except: ['store']),
        ];
    }
 
    // ...
}

It is recommended to specify middleware using routing.
